# Cakephp related tables show id's instead of values

Tags: cakephp

i think i have all 'baked' all my relationships correctly but my 'related' table shows id's instead of values.

my db has 3 tables. candidates, qualificationlookups, qualifications.
qualificationlookups, links candidates to qualifications using the id of the candidate and the id of the qualification.

in my view view, for 'candidates', i have a 'related qualificationlookups' table. (generated by baking a candidate hasmany qualificationlookups and a qualificationlookups belongsto candidate relationship)

in my edit view, for 'qualificationlookups', i can correctly set up the candidates and qualifications fields as dropdowns so i know 'qualificationlookups's relationships are fine.

So how do i ask cakephp to list the name of the qualification (from 'qualifications' table) in the 'related qualificationlookups' table on a candidate's page?

i must be missing something...

could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks, Vauneen

Comment: Is there any other data in the `qualificationlookups` table besides keys to the other two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no other data being stored in the `qualificationlookups` table, change the relationship to `candidates -> HABTM -> qualifications`.

To do this, you first need to drop the `qualificationlookups` table.  Create a new table called `candidates_qualifications` with two indexes, `candidate_id` and `qualification_id`.

In your `Candidate` and `Qualification` models, define a [HABTM Relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM).  You do not need to make a new `CandidatesQualification` Model, cake will do it on the fly.

Comment: following on from this, is there a built-in way to then add to the linked tables.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever CakePHP automagically fetches lists from your tables, it uses the `id` key for the value and the `$displayField` for the text.

If your table has a `name` or `title` field, CakePHP automatically displays it as the display field. So, either rename the field that you want as your display field (say, `candidate_name` to just `name`) or set the `$displayField` variable in your model:

```
class Candidate extends AppModel {
    var $displayField = 'candidate_name';
}
```

HTH.

Comment: This was my first thought, as well.  I think his problem is that he was doing a `hasMany` relationship to a join table that only has key columns, and then pulling one-association-deep.

Comment: Ah, was trying to give a different answer/perspective than what was already submitted. Cheers :-)